# Remove borders in plotly treemap

Tags: r, plotly, treemap

I'm currently plotting some data using the plotly R library for the plot type `treemap`.

When plotting the data, I get a big top border (and smaller ones on right, left and bottom) as visible in this example [image: Treemap Plotly]

I would like to eliminate these borders, in order to have something similar to this [image: Treemap without borders]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The borders can be removed by combing a zero line width with zero tile padding.

Here's an example that Plotly has put on their site with the standard borders.

```
# example from at https://plotly.com/r/treemaps/
plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=c("Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"),
  parents=c("", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve")
)
```

[image]

Here is the same plot without borders.

```
# no borders
plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=c("Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"),
  parents=c("", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve"),
  marker = list(line = list(width = 0)),
  tiling = list(pad = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kat . In fact, the problem is, that the parent category title takes space, which is not accounted in the sum of the children. In the question's solution, this issue is resolved, by adding the name of the children in the bottom edge, while the parents name (and defining color) is in the top left edge.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared your data and your code I could help a bit more. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: How can I make it so that Enoch fills up more of the awan square (the borders seem too big).